# Restricting cpu cores in a docker container

Tags: bash, docker, cpu

I'm trying to restrict the CPUs of the container using the docker --cpuset-cpus option. But I'm not getting the desired result for some reason. For example the following command should just print 1:

```
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus=0 ubuntu:latest grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

But I get the result as 4 (4 is the number of cpus shown in my host). This is so for any OS.

```
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus=0 centos grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus=0 alpine grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l

Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:45 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:24 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Am I wrong in my understanding of the cpuset-cpus option? If so, what is the exact parameter that I need to pass to get the desired behavior I'm expecting? (`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` should output 1)

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to use less CPU in percentage or in numbers. Like you want to use 50% of your CPU, or 2 CPU's?

```
$ docker run -it --cpuset-cpus="0-2" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

This means processes in container can be executed on cpu 0, cpu 1 and cpu 2.

The `--cpu-quota` flag limits the container’s CPU usage. The default 0 value allows the container to take 100% of a CPU resource (1 CPU).

It seems that there is an issue about that https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20770

try to use something similar to

```
docker run --rm --cpuset-cpus=0,1 ubuntu sh -c "cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus"
```

And check if that works.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the kernel's CPU sets don't affect the proc file in any way.